# Java DOM: transforming a node to a root element

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have the following XML file (SOAP response) that I'm trying to map to a Java object :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:AffaireByTiersResponse xmlns:ns2="http://service.hibernate.com/">
      <Affaire>
        <code_produit>Cred</code_produit>
        <id>1</id>
        <montant_fin>2000.0</montant_fin>
        <id_tier>1</id_tier>
      </Affaire>
      <Affaire>
        <code_produit>Cred</code_produit>
        <id>2</id>
        <montant_fin>25000.0</montant_fin>
        <id_tier>1</id_tier>
      </Affaire>
    </ns2:AffaireByTiersResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

in order to marshall the file I need to keep only the tag `<AffaireByTiersResponse>` as root element and change its name to `<Affaires>`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: "Map to a Java object"... do you mean JAXB or similar?

Comment: Yes i plan on using JAXB Unmarshaller (i've already tested it)

Comment: AFAIK, you can rename the node with the [Document#renameNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#renameNode-org.w3c.dom.Node-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). The Unmarshaller can then unmarshal that Element. Not sure about the details though. So you have to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting the underlying content from the SOAP envelop can be done using `javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory`.

```
String example = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("input.xml")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null,
        new ByteArrayInputStream(example.getBytes()));

Document doc = message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument();

Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
```

The root node can then be renamed

```
doc.renameNode(root, root.getNamespaceURI(), "Affaires");
```

and this document can then be passed into the JAXB unmarshaller

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Affaires.class).createUnmarshaller();
Affaires farm = (Affaires) unmarshaller.unmarshal(doc);
```

Comment: thanks a bunch,
stupid me didn't know about `Document doc = message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument();` and renameNode() function.

Comment: I know this answer is pretty old, but would changing the root element before sending back a response not differ from the generated WSDL?